# What is the CFT?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

What is the CFT achievement called Crazy Freaking Skills? I have tried all vechiles and none work, I am not sure what the CFT is.

Answer (score 1):

The CFT is the [Crazy Freaking Teleporter](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Freaking_Teleporter).

According to the [wiki](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Freaking_Skills), you must

> Get a best distance of over 800m in the CFT.

Comment: Ok thank you sooooo much Darakath do you know a lot about jet pack if you do I will just ask you next time